# Why does this loop scale with quadratic time

Tags: python, loops, numpy, time, time-complexity

I am rearranging a matrix in numpy using the code below

```
t1=time.time()

df1=train1[1,1:52]
for i in xrange(40):
    for j in xrange(52,551):
        x=train1[i,(j-51):j]
        df1=np.vstack((df1,x))

t2=time.time()
t=t2-t1
```

While running the loop for the outer loop for 5 turns [ i in xrange(5) and j unchanged ], it takes <1 sec. For 10 turns, it takes ~4 secs; for 20 turns, it takes ~18 secs; for 40 turns, ~85 secs.

Can someone please clarify why the loop is scaling in quadratic time, even when we increase the outer loop linearly.

Thanks

PS:
The matrix I am using here is the training set for the Kaggle training set for the Wikipedia competition. You can download train_1.csv from link which I have read into a pandas dataframe and then converted to a numpy matrix (i.e. train1) using .to_matrix()

Comment: Did you try looking at execution times for the smaller parts of your code? I'm thinking in particular about checking the time it takes to loop over `j` every time, and the time it takes to run the lines within your loop over `j`. That would give you some insights on where exactly the execution time changes unexpectedly.

Comment: Also, can you provide us with a working example? Without access to `train1` we can't run the code ourselves and test things to understand what's going on...

Comment: Hi Arthur
The matrix I am using here is the training set for the Kaggle training set for the Wikipedia competition. You can download train_1.csv from [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/web-traffic-time-series-forecasting/data) which I have read into a pandas dataframe and then converted to a numpy matrix (i.e. `train1`) using .to_matrix(). Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Yati, it would be great if you could update your question with that information! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the call to `vstack` creates a copy of `df1` in each iteration. Sice the size of `df1` varies linearly with the outer loop range, you get your quadratic runtime.

Profiling the code shows that most of the time is spent in `concatenate`, which is called by `vstack`:

```
In [13]: cProfile.run('q.proc()')
         259486 function calls in 19.759 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.001    0.001   19.759   19.759 <string>:1(<module>)
    39920    0.030    0.000    0.036    0.000 numeric.py:534(asanyarray)
    19960    0.031    0.000   15.037    0.001 shape_base.py:182(vstack)
    19960    0.020    0.000    0.121    0.000 shape_base.py:237(<listcomp>)
    39920    0.057    0.000    0.101    0.000 shape_base.py:63(atleast_2d)
        1    4.720    4.720   19.758   19.758 temp.py:6(proc)
        1    0.000    0.000   19.759   19.759 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    39920    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
    39920    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
    19960   14.886    0.001   14.886    0.001 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.concatenate}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
    39920    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

You could create a list of `x`'s and concatenate after the loop.

Edit: I defined `train1` as `np.random.rand(100,600)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Yakym

Comment: Damn, you got there a lot quicker than me! Can you give us some details about how to get the output you're showing? It's a quite useful feature that I didn't know existed :o

Comment: It's from `cProfile.run` in the standard library. Handy indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code with more time checks and using a random generated matrix for `train1`:

```
import time
import numpy as np

t_total=time.time()
train1=np.random.random((20, 550))
df1=train1[1,1:52]
for i in range(5):
    t1 = time.time()
    tj = []
    for j in range(52,551):
        t2 = time.time()
        x=train1[i,(j-51):j]
        df1=np.concatenate((df1,x),axis=0)
        tj.append(time.time()-t2) 
    print("Time to loop on j:", time.time()-t1)
    print("Average time for each j:", np.mean(tj))

print("Total time:", time.time()-t_total)
```

When I run this I get the following output, showing that clearly every loop gets longer and longer.

```
Time to loop on j: 0.009780406951904297
Average time for each j: 1.9157577851e-05
Time to loop on j: 0.02693343162536621
Average time for each j: 5.33469932113e-05
Time to loop on j: 0.06705927848815918
Average time for each j: 0.000133752822876
Time to loop on j: 0.08919048309326172
Average time for each j: 0.000178138813179
Time to loop on j: 0.11366486549377441
Average time for each j: 0.000227188060661
Total time: 0.3072977066040039
```

My guess is: `np.vstack` simply takes more time as the size of matrices input increases, and that's what's causing your execution time to increase exponentially. I can't seem to find an equivalent of numpy that would deal with this issue however... A solution that works is to store in a list all the array you want to stack, then compute the stack in the end:

```
import time
import numpy as np

t_total=time.time()
train1=np.random.random((20, 550))
df1=[train1[1,1:52]]
for i in range(5):
    t1 = time.time()
    tj = []
    for j in range(52,551):
        t2 = time.time()
        x=train1[i,(j-51):j]
        df1.append(x)
        tj.append(time.time()-t2) 
    print("Time to loop on j:", time.time()-t1)
    print("Average time for each j:", np.mean(tj))
df1 = np.vstack(df1)
print("Total time:", time.time()-t_total)
```

And the running times this gets me:

```
Time to loop on j: 0.0005383491516113281
Average time for each j: 7.99347260194e-07
Time to loop on j: 0.0005192756652832031
Average time for each j: 7.58734876981e-07
Time to loop on j: 0.0005254745483398438
Average time for each j: 7.73546452035e-07
Time to loop on j: 0.0005245208740234375
Average time for each j: 7.73546452035e-07
Time to loop on j: 0.0005295276641845703
Average time for each j: 7.80235550447e-07
Total time: 0.008821249008178711
```

It seems that stacking many small arrays is easier than stacking big arrays, or something like that. Then appending an object of fixed size to a list has a fixed cost whatever the size of the list.

Comment: Thank you, Arthur. Your answer was very helpful